# Do not able to connect with mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

While I am trying to connect with `mysql` in `PHP`.

It is showing its code in the browser instead of running the code.

please help I am new to PHP.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cki');
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo "not connected";
    }else{
        echo "connected";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: You need to configure PHP Setting in apache.

Comment: Are you having any output?

Comment: Are you running on a server or in somthing like wamp/xamp. Because if the code is just displaying like text and not executing the code it likes to be that the compiler is not working.

Answer (score 0):

this is OS specific, (if the user works in MYSQL shell that is) **AS A SECURITY RESTRAINT you also may not connect from php with `root` / `no password`** so run `$ sudo mysql_secure_installation` first

EG:

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

follow the prompts set a root password

then login to mysql as that root user and do this

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON cki.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

if you are using centos you do

```
  $ sudo yum install php php-mysql mysql-server
  $ sudo service httpd restart
```

if you are using debian you do

```
  $ sudo apt-get install php php-mysql mysql-server
  $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

then you ensure that you have turned off `selinux` in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`

finally

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','new_user','new_password','cki');
    if(!$con)
    {
        echo "not connected";
    }else{
        echo "connected";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Isn't it more likely that php isn't configured at all, since they're seeing php code when visiting the page instead or rendered html?

Comment: lol I actually put `install php` in the first draft then removed it for some reason, i've readded it